# Como remover encriptação de Aleatoria PHP

Tags: php, html, criptografia, link, encode

Possuo um codigo porem toda vez ao atualizar a pagina ele gera uma chave de encriptação aleatoria, gostaria de saber como deixa-lo para gerar uma chave unica para cada url, abaixo segue o codigo:

```js
$gKey = 'welcometoapicodesdotcomthisiskey';
function decode($pData)
{
    global $gKey;
    $lData = str_replace(' ','+', $pData);
    $lBase64Decoded_Payload = base64_decode($lData);
    $lEncrypted_PlainText = substr($lBase64Decoded_Payload, 16);
    $lIV = substr($lBase64Decoded_Payload, 0, 16);
    $lDecrypted_PlainText = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $gKey, $lEncrypted_PlainText, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $lIV);
    $lBase64Decoded_PlainText = base64_decode($lDecrypted_PlainText);
    return $lBase64Decoded_PlainText;
}

function encode($pData)
{
    global $gKey;
    $lBase64Encoded_PlainText = base64_encode($pData);
    $lIV = GenerateIV();
    $lEncrypted_PlainText = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $gKey, $lBase64Encoded_PlainText, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $lIV);
    $lPayload = $lIV.$lEncrypted_PlainText;
    $lBase64Encoded_Payload = base64_encode($lPayload);
    return $lBase64Encoded_Payload;
}

function GenerateIV()
{
    $lIV = mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
    while(strlen($lIV) < 16)
    {
        $lIV .= "\0";
    }
    return $lIV;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A chave de encriptação é fixa em seu código, ela é exatamente o que está definido em:

```
$gKey = 'welcometoapicodesdotcomthisiskey';
```

Com essa chave você pode encriptar e decriptar os textos, assim como qualquer outra pessoa que saiba (ou descubra) essa chave.

---

O que ocorre é que as cifras precisam de um valor único, o Nonce. No caso do método CBC chama-se IV (que é o primeiro bloco), e ele deve ser único e ainda aleatório. O IV é um dado público, portanto qualquer um pode ter acesso à ele, inclusive ele é concatenado no inicio (`$lIV.$lEncrypted_PlainText;`).

O que é gerado "toda vez que atualiza a pagina" é o IV, este comportamento está certo.

---

É possível gerar IV únicos, porém determinísticos, porém isso não é recomendado em geral, mas pode ser feito usando algum KDF, mas não me arrisco e dar alguma sugestão. Além disso, o `mcrypt_*` já é considerado obsoleto, então não acredito que vale a pena usar isso.